# Selenium not loading show more in meetup tech

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have spent the last few days to fix this with no success :( could anyone help? basically for a given city in the meetup website, when selenium clicks "show more" it loads but nothing appears, but if I do it manually on the same link it does. Any help would be much appreciated. PS I am a newbie so don't be hard :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import time
#here is a link to an excel file with links like:
#https://www.meetup.com/find/tech/?allMeetups=true&radius=5&userFreeform=Rio+de+Janeiro%2C+Brazil&mcId=c1002406&change=yes&sort=recommended&eventFilter=mysugg
df = pd.read_excel(r'G:\....\Cities_tech_try.xlsx')

df['Group_count'] = np.nan
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    PATH = 'C:\\temp\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

    URL=row['Link']
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(URL)
    #driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='80%'")
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span').click() 
        time.sleep(5)
        while True:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            time.sleep(5)
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                break
        
        df.loc[index,'Group_count'] = len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3'))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        df.loc[index,'Group_count'] = len(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3'))
```

Comment: I have opened the link which you have commented on and went to the "show more" button and clicked it manually. It is not loading more results for me. The last Item I am seeling in the list is "BeerChain".

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://www.meetup.com/find/?allMeetups=true&radius=100&userFreeform=Rio+de+Janeiro%2C+Brazil&mcId=c1002406&mcName=Rio+de+Janeiro%2C+BR&sort=recommended'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\seleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
getr = browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()

def clickonce():
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Show more')]").click()

def scrolldown():
    time.sleep(3)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)

clickonce()
while True:
    scrolldown()
```